# npm error: cloning into bare repository + unable to find remote helper for https

Tags: git, meteor, npm

I'm trying to add html5_rtsp_player (https://github.com/Streamedian/html5_rtsp_player) to my meteor.js web-service, but there are some npm errors I can't solve

Here is my command:

```
meteor npm install git://github.com/Streamedian/html5_rtsp_player.git
```

Here is the output:

```
npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\Bo\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.2_3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\.npm\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror https://github.com/kreopt/jsencrypt.git C:\Users\Bo\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.2_3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\.npm\_git-remotes\git-https-github-com-kreopt-jsencrypt-git-711f0eab: Cloning into bare repository 'C:\Users\Bo\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.2_3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\.npm\_git-remotes\git-https-github-com-kreopt-jsencrypt-git-711f0eab'...
npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\Bo\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.2_3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\.npm\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror https://github.com/kreopt/jsencrypt.git C:\Users\Bo\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.2_3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\.npm\_git-remotes\git-https-github-com-kreopt-jsencrypt-git-711f0eab: fatal: Unable to find remote helper for 'https'
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Users\\Bo\\AppData\\Local\\.meteor\\packages\\meteor-tool\\1.4.2_3\\mt-os.windows.x86_32\\dev_bundle\\bin\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Bo\\AppData\\Local\\.meteor\\packages\\meteor-tool\\1.4.2_3\\mt-os.windows.x86_32\\dev_bundle\\lib\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "git+https://github.com/Streamedian/html5_rtsp_player.git" "-g"
npm ERR! node v4.6.2
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.9
npm ERR! code 128

npm ERR! Command failed: git -c core.longpaths=true clone --template=C:\Users\Bo\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.2_3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\.npm\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror https://github.com/kreopt/jsencrypt.git C:\Users\Bo\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.2_3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\.npm\_git-remotes\git-https-github-com-kreopt-jsencrypt-git-711f0eab
npm ERR! Cloning into bare repository 'C:\Users\Bo\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.2_3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\.npm\_git-remotes\git-https-github-com-kreopt-jsencrypt-git-711f0eab'...
npm ERR! fatal: Unable to find remote helper for 'https'
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Bo\myapp\npm-debug.log
```

I already tried to install curl.exe and tried install via git bash, but it didn't seem to help. What else can I do to improve it?